# Can we write a test application which fires request on sever, from all around the globe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, dns, automated-tests, http-proxy

I have a running AWS application, I recently blocked its access from Russia using Geolocation Routing feature. 
How can i write a test application which fires request on my application from all around the globe ?

Comment: this doesn't entirely make sense. Do you want to test access to the server from various countries to ensure it works? You'll need access to servers in various countries, in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pointed out by @tedder42 is comments you need to originate the traffic from the geographic location you are blocking in order to test this. You will need to have IPs in that location *or* you can use a proxy server in that region.

Here is a list of free proxies you might try: http://proxylist.hidemyass.com (there are other options around).

Configure your test app to have a list of proxies, and switch between them when sending the traffic.

Also, with geolocation, there is nothing preventing somebody from those geographies to send the traffic through a proxy in a geography you allow (i.e. geolocation is not 100% bulletproof - in fact the main reason people e use it is to improve latency/throughput not to block traffic)